# Suggest me some good practices to keep socket-io connected in Android oreo

Tags: java, android

The background services are not encouraged any more from Android Oreo (>25). I want the socket to keep connected in my chat application even when the app is closed.
How can I implement new changes to android 26?

Some people says, use **JobIntentService**

Some people says, use **JobService**

Some people says, use **JobScheduler**

Some people says, start service as **Foreground Service**

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This work flow is already done. I would like to know about running background services in Android Oreo.

Comment: i am also looking for this kind of solution from long time ago, just like what's app, what exactly they are using.

Comment: Is there any possibility of looking at this in another light? is there really any need to keep the socket connection open? what is the desired behavior you are looking for?

Comment: @Eddnav Yes , i need socket keep connected for a real time communication and the device need to know when a message arrives through the socket connection even app is removed from the tray.

Comment: Hmm I don't know much about your server side, but is there anything stopping you from just sending a push notification to the other device when a message is sent to that user and the connection is closed? This way the user will just open the app again and the connection can be recreated, so messages can be sent in he normal fashion again. I think the first order of the day here is to try to avoid this constant connection above everything else. If anything, that can't be healthy battery wise regardless of the target API level.

Comment: you want to keep it alive permanently when your app is closed? i would suggest to redefine your use case.

Comment: Do what many messaging applications do: **push notifications** , Firebase offers that service

Comment: So.. who gets the bounty? :p

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I faced the exact same problem working on a chat application so I know your pain. Our conclusion was:

> you don't keep a connection alive 24/7, if you need to deliver a
>   message to an user that has no connection alive, send a push message
>   via Firebase.

If you want to keep a connection alive in background, you will face many problems. The first one, targeting Oreo, is that if your app is in background (definition of "background" in this context is [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html#services)) it won't be allowed to run except for small time windows.

You can definitely use `JobScheduler` to run periodic tasks, they won't be executed at exact intervals or times to reduce battery usage (which is good) but it won't help you in keeping a connection alive. At best, you can use `JobScheduler` to periodically pull messages from you server. In order to use `JobScheduler` you need to create a `JobService` class.

`JobIntentService` is a new class introduced in API 26 of support library. It is a replacement for `IntentService`, it will run as a `JobService` on android API 26+ and as a `Service` (similar to `IntentService` in the sense that it will execute code in a background thread) on older APIs. On Oreo its background execution will still be limited so it won't help you in keeping a connection alive.

Using a foreground `Service` can really help you reducing the likelihood of the process being killed, but, you will need to display a permanent notification. It doesn't sound like a good solution for a chat app.

If you still think that having a 24/7 connection alive is a viable option, you need to consider also doze mode. You could ask the user to whitelist your app to run even in doze mode but you should have a very good reason to do that. Again, you would face the other bg execution limit in Oreo.

Another issue you will face is *other apps*. There are resources management apps that will aggressively kill other apps in bg to reduce memory and battery usage. For instance, I cursed [this one](http://www.samsung.com/global/galaxy/what-is/smart-manager/) quite a bit.

Another issue is created by *android*. When the system is running low on memory, it will start killing processes of apps in bg. There is a an order in which they're killed, if I recall correctly should take into account last time it was in fg and current memory usage. Not the worst of the problems but still, it happens.

Then, if I still haven't convinced you in giving up the idea of the permanent connection, let me share with you yet another problem you would face. Some vendors implements *extremely aggressive* policies when it comes to killing bg processes, so that they're battery will last longer. For instance, Xiaomi.

Last tip, unrelated, but it took us a while to figure this out so I'm going to share it. If the user force stops your app from settings, your app is *dead* (that is, "stopped state") until the user actively launches it again, it won't even receive Firebase push messages.

Comment: I have a ride hailing app, I have no other choice but to maintain socket connection in the background.

What should I use?

Comment: @MohsinFalak I'd go with a foreground service

Comment: I have foreground service, wakelock and battery optimisation disabled. And I still have disconnection issues because the chinese devices have their custom battery features. I have to manually goto the settings of such devices and enable background access for my app. Then it works just fine.
https://dontkillmyapp.com

So my question is will work manager help with my situation ?

Comment: @MohsinFalak I think that with work manager you could schedule a poll mechanism instead of keeping the connection open

Comment: My usecase doesn't allow me to stop the connection. I need real time availability of the driver to be able for it to get assigned a trip. (Or is there anyother approach you can suggest?)

My real questions is, 

Does work manager has any advantages over using:
Foreground service, wakelock and battery optimisation disabled.

Comment: @MohsinFalak I don't know, IIRC work manager wasn't intended to keep your app alive at all costs but rather to let your app perform defined background tasks. You can try with a long-running worker and see if it doesn't get killed eventually.

Answer (score 5):

If your server is configured on [XMPP](https://xmpp.org/about/), then it would be easy for you.
Actually, there isn't any need to keep the socket alive at all the time. This is very expensive for the battery and I'm sure you don't want that.

Case: You are working on a Messaging app.

If your socket is broken, then the client will receive the message in the form of Google [FIREBASE](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) notification. And the moment your client will receive a notification from firebase, just enable the socket, and you'll be back on track.
The reason I suggested you to use `XMPP` is because XMPP *maintains a queue of undelivered/offline messages*. And when your socket is connected again, you simply pull the offline messages from the server.

I don't think this will help you out, but this may make a room for some another idea for you.

Comment: I have a ride hailing app, I have no other choice but to maintain socket connection in the background.

What should I use?

Comment: you'll need to implement VOIP to allow your app to run a service in the background, even if the user closes the app (not kill)

Comment: Do you mean I need trick the system into thinking that I'm on a VOIP call?
Can you please elaborate on that?

Comment: I currently have a foreground service, wakelock and battery optimisation disbaled. App works perfect on Pixel devices!
I'm only having issue on chinese devices where I have to manually go to the settings and enable "allow background"...